# android multiple choice quiz app

Tags: android

hello there i am new to android programming i have created an android multiple choice quiz app using array . the problem is when all the question are done at the end i want that a new activity comes and it shows the calculated result.How and Where i will write code for it Plz help

```
public class QuestionLibrary {

private String mQuestions[] = {
        "which number comes in the following series ? 10 50 250 1250__?__",
        "Free is to imprison as Forgive is to_____?",
        "My Mother is Sister of your Brother,what relation m i to you?",
        "Spot out the stranger in the following?"
};

private String mChoices[][] = {
        {"1350","6250","6500","1550"},
        {"Accuse","Accept","Condemn","Punish"},
        {"Uncle","Brother","Cousin","Nephew"},
        {"Atheist","Godly","Holy","Pious"}

};
private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {
        "6250",
        "Punish",
        "Cousin",
        "Atheist"
};
public String getQuestion(int a) {
    String question = mQuestions[a];
    return question;
}
public String getChoice1(int a) {
    String choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
    return choice0;
}
public String getChoice2(int a) {
    String choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
    return choice1;
}
public String getChoice3(int a) {
    String choice2 = mChoices[a][2];
    return choice2;
}
public String getChoice4(int a) {
    String choice3 = mChoices[a][3];
    return choice3;
}
public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
    String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
    return answer;
}
```

Here is the Main Activity

```
mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    mButtonChoice4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice4);

    updateQuestion();

    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mButtonChoice1.getText()== mAnswer)
            {

                mScore+=1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
    mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mButtonChoice2.getText()== mAnswer)
            {

                mScore+=1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
    mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mButtonChoice3.getText()== mAnswer)
            {

                mScore+=1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
    mButtonChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mButtonChoice4.getText()== mAnswer)
            {

                mScore+=1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void updateQuestion()
{
    mQuestionView.setText(questionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice1.setText(questionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice2.setText(questionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice3.setText(questionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice4.setText(questionLibrary.getChoice4(mQuestionNumber));
    mAnswer = questionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
    mQuestionNumber++;
}
private void updateScore(int point)
{
    mScoreView.setText(""+mScore);
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: hey I have the similar application, but getting this error help me out:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following piece of code in the updateQuestion method.

```
if(mQuestionNumber>3)
{
Intent resultIntent = new Intent (this, ResultActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra('SCORE',mScore);
startActivity(resultIntent);
}
```

In your Result activity get the extra value and display it through a text view